# Creating Multiple Nuspec files

Tags: deployment, nuget, nuspec

I am currently trying to publish a load of nuget packages for all the projects in [this solution](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/tree/master/Myre). The projects are setup in a simple tree, with Myre being the base project and everything depending on it:

```
Myre <- Myre.Debugging <- Myre.Debugging.UI <- Myre.UI
Myre <- Myre.UI
Myre <- Myre.Entities <- Myre.Graphics
```

I'm trying to package up each separate project as a nuget package with the correct dependencies on the other Myre subproject packages as necessary.

My first step was to make a package for [Myre](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Myre/) ([nuspec](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/blob/master/Myre/Myre/Myre.nuspec) and [bat file of process](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/blob/master/Myre/Myre/build-nuget.bat)). This seems to work nicely, the gallery shows Myre as having a *ninject* (another nuget package) dependency and all is well.

The problem comes when I tried to make the next package. [Myre.Debugging](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/tree/master/Myre/Myre.Debugging) depends upon Myre (with a normal project reference) and nothing else. Using [this nuspec](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/blob/master/Myre/Myre.Debugging/Myre.Debugging.nuspec) with nuget pack (verbose) gives:

```
Attempting to build package from '(x86) Myre.Debugging.csproj'.
Packing files from 'C:\Long_Path\Myre\Myre.Debugging\bin\x86\Release'.
Add file 'C:\Long_Path\Myre\Myre.Debugging\bin\x86\Release\Myre.Debugging.dll' to package as 'lib\net40-Client\Myre.Debugging.dll'
Add file 'C:\Long_Path\Myre\Myre\bin\x86\Release\Myre.dll' to package as 'lib\net40-Client\Myre.dll'
Add file 'C:\Long_Path\Myre\Myre\bin\x86\Release\Myre.XML' to package as 'lib\net40-Client\Myre.XML'
Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies

Id: Myre.Debugging
Version: 1.0.0.2
Authors: Microsoft
Description: Description
Dependencies: Ninject (= 3.0.1.10)

Added file 'lib\net40-Client\Myre.Debugging.dll'.
Added file 'lib\net40-Client\Myre.dll'.
Added file 'lib\net40-Client\Myre.XML'.

Successfully created package 'C:\Long_Path\Myre\Myre.Debugging\Myre.Debugging.1.0.0.2.nupkg'.
```

As you can see it picks up a packages.config file (presumably from Myre since there isn't one [here](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/tree/master/Myre/Myre.Debugging)) which it then determines a Ninject dependency from. If I wanted Myre.Debugging and Myre to be a single package that would be fine. However this is *not* what I want, I want Myre.Debugging to pick up a dependency on the Myre package.

How can I setup nuget to use Myre as a package reference and not simply to copy the Myre assemblies into the Myre.Debugging package?

Edit:: I tried not using *-IncludeReferencedProjects* and specifying:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Myre" version="1.0.0.1" />
</dependencies>
```

But for some reason this just creates a package with no dependencies at all! Even if manually specifying dependencies like this did work, it's hardly ideal.

Comment: If anyone visits my nuget page and sees lots of Myre projects that's because I've created all the nuspec files by hand for now. But that's really not a very good long term solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [NuGet command line reference for the Pack command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command), the `IncludeReferencedProjects` switch works as follows:

> Include referenced projects either as dependencies or as part of the package. If a referenced project has a corresponding nuspec file that has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is added as a dependency. Otherwise, the referenced project is added as part of the package.

In your case, [Myre.Debugging.nuspec](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/blob/master/Myre/Myre.Debugging/Myre.Debugging.nuspec) does not match the project file names: [(x86) Myre.Debugging.csproj](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/blob/master/Myre/Myre.Debugging/%28x86%29%20Myre.Debugging.csproj), etc.  I suspect that you'll need to match up those file names to get that command line option to work.

Alternatively, if you want to get this to work with a `<dependencies>` element in your nuspec file, you may be facing another variant on the name mismatch problem.  Your [Myre.nuspec](https://github.com/martindevans/Myre/blob/master/Myre/Myre/Myre.nuspec) file defines its ID as follows:

> <id>$id$</id>

The [NuSpec reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) says that the `$id$` token is replaced by "The Assembly name."  If it's talking about the name of the DLL (ignoring the extension), then I think the generated IDs will be `(x86) Myre`, etc.  You might want to try hard-coding the ID temporarily just to see if that resolves the issue.

I haven't tried making these suggested changes, and I can't guarantee they will work, but I hope this points you in the right direction.  Good luck!